# Extendscript Debugger Visual Studio Code Link to Photoshop App

Tags: visual-studio-code, photoshop

I'm using ExtendScript Debugger with VS Code 1.85.1. I've run scripts directly from Photoshop and they worked, however, I want to use the debugger running in Visual Studio Code and have been following tutorials from various sources. I'm just testing to see that I can link to Photoshop and get some basic information back about layers.  The following is my code so far:

```
main();
function main(){
   alert("Hello");
   var doc=app.activedocument;

   var myWindow = new Window("palette","My Window",undefined);
   myWindow.orientation="row";
```

This launches ok and pops up an alert window in Photoshop. But is then should pop up a window but doesn't.  There are no errors, however, intellisense does not have myWindow.show() which I think is what will display to window.  Possibly I have missed a step in setting up VS Code.